# How to setup day month calculation in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have dataset on date of births e.g.

```
14-Dec-98,
23-Nov-70,
14-Dec-67,
7-Jan-19,
14-Dec-45,
7-Jan-88
```

I want to plot a graph of number of birthdays on a day. That is;

```
14-Dec -- 3,
23-Nov -- 1,
7-Jan --- 2,
```

How should I write the calculated field formula??

Comment: Welcome to SO which is a great forum to learn and share. Please do mention what did you try and what worked and didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your date field is recognised by Tableau as a date, extract the day and month from that field.

DAY([DOB])
MONTH([DOB])

Combine these and make them back into a date (assuming the data source accepts MAKEDATE)

MAKEDATE(2020, MONTH([DOB]), DAY([DOB]))

Format the new made date field to remove the year.

Comment: Yes to try this but this logic should work. Thanks. Also it doesn't matter what year you put in the makedate formula the logic will still hold true. Right? Thanks.

Comment: Right, the year is irrelevant, although keep it the same for all. It'll be removed with the formatting any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
{ FIXED MONTH([Date of Birth]), DAY([Date of Birth]):COUNT([Number of Records])}
```